# How do I write the argument verifications for functions in R. Can glue be used?

Tags: r, function, tidyverse

I'm pretty new to writing functions in `r`.  I've come up with a sample function.  I'm looking for help with the following:

- I have a function that has character choices that can be one of a selection of specific choices
- I want to check that the choice is a part of that character vector of choices (without title case mattering)
- I'd also like to use `glue::glue` if possible so that I can be more specific with my error message. Example below.

Can you also show me the difference in code to write errors if only 1 choice is allowed in the character vector, or more than one choice is allowed?

```
library(stringr)

sample_function <- function(choice = c("apples", "bananas", "cherries")) {

allowed_choices <- c("apples", "bananas", "cherries")


# match to lowercase 
choice <- str_to_lower(choice)

if(!choice %in% allowed_choices){
  stop("Please choose Apples, Bananas, or Cherries")
}

}

sample_function(choice = "Test")
#> Error in sample_function(choice = "Test"): Please choose Apples, Bananas, or Cherries
Created on 2019-11-18 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

Can I do something like the below in the stop message.  I'd want the character vector to be separated by commas:

```
glue::glue("{choice} is not a valid choice.  Please choose from: {allowed_choices}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a glue function `glue_collapse` for collapsing vectors like this with an "or" (or something else) before the last element

```
sample_function <- function(choice = c("apples", "bananas", "cherries")) {

  allowed_choices <- c("apples", "bananas", "cherries")
  allowed_choices_coll <- glue_collapse(allowed_choices, sep = ', ', last = ' or ')

  # match to lowercase 
  choice <- str_to_lower(choice)
  if(!choice %in% allowed_choices){
    stop(
      glue::glue("{choice} is not a valid choice.  Please choose from: {allowed_choices_coll}")
    )
  }

}

sample_function(choice = 'mango')

# Error in sample_function(choice = "mango") : 
#   mango is not a valid choice.  Please choose from: apples, bananas or cherries
```

Comment: Thanks!  So I have to always list the character vector of choices within the function as well?

Comment: If you want to use the vector of choices in the error message you need to have that vector available to the function. Best practice is to declare the vector inside the function so it is self-contained, but technically if you defined `allowed_choices` in the global envirnment your function would still find it and be able to use for the error message. Assuming the user has provided their own argument for `choice` I don't know of any way to access the default value. By the way, running this function with the default value will mean your `if` condition is a vector, generating a warning

Comment: Thanks!  How do you recommend setting up the function?  Just listing one choice, and putting the rest of the choices in the documentation?

Comment: I guess it depends on how the function should work. If you want it to possibly accept a length >1 vector you could just change the if to `if(!all(choice %in% allowed_choices))`. Otherwise, yeah, I would just provide a single default value or no default and document the choices in the docs as you say.

Answer (score 0):

We can collapse with `str_c` from `stringr` and use that in the `glue`

```
library(stringr)

sample_function <- function(choice = c("apples", "bananas", "cherries")) {

allowed_choices <- c("apples", "bananas", "cherries")


# match to lowercase 
choice <- str_to_lower(choice)

concat_choices <- str_c(allowed_choices, collapse=", ")

if(!choice %in% allowed_choices){
  stop(glue::glue("{choice} is not a valid choice.  Please choose from: {concat_choices}"))
}

}
```

-testing

```
sample_function(choice = "Test")
```

> Error in sample_function(choice = "Test") : 
>     test is not a valid choice.  Please choose from: apples, bananas, cherries

Answer (score 0):

I tend to do something like the following:

```r
sample_function <- function(choice = c("apples", "bananas", "cherries")) {
  allowed_choices <- c("apples", "bananas", "cherries")

  extra_choices <- setdiff(choice, allowed_choices)
  if (length(extra_choices)) {
    stop("unrecognized 'choice': ", paste(sQuote(extra_choices), collapse = ","))
    # optional alternative
    stop("'choice' must be from ", paste(sQuote(allowed_choices), collapse = ","))
  }
}
```

assuming that you are allowing more than one choice.

Whether you use `glue` or not is up to you, but the `paste(..., collapse)` thing might be useful.